# Java - Using the output from one class in another

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that takes the output of adding two numbers in one class together and adds it to a different number. Here is the first class:

```
public class Add{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 5;
        int b = 5;
        int c = a + b;
        System.out.println(c);

        }   
}
```

And the second:

```
public class AddExtra{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Add a = new Add();

    int b = 5;
    int c = a.value+b;

    System.out.println(c);
    }   
}
```

How do I get this to work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
public class Add{
    public int c; // public variable

    public Add() { // This is a constructor
                   // It will run every time you type "new Add()"
        int a = 5;
        int b = 5;
        c = a + b;
    }   
}
```

Then, you can do this:

```
public class AddExtra{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Add a = new Add(); // Here, the constructor is run

        int b = 5;
        int c = a.c + b; // Access "a.c" because "c" is a public variable now

        System.out.println(c);
    }   
}
```

[Read more about constructors here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Comment: I hope you wouldn't actually advise making a public field. For learning purposes, maybe.

Comment: @TimS. Yes, partly, but in this case there is really no need to add a getter (or setter). In this small example it would really not be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

- You need to give the Add class a *public `add(...)` method*,
- have this method accept an int parameter,
- have it add a constant int to the int passed in,
- and then have it return the sum.
- If you want it to add two numbers, rather than a number and a constant, then give the method *two* int parameters, and add them together in the method.

Then create another class,

- In this other class you can create an Add instance,
- call the `add(myInt)` method,
- and print the result returned.